# simpleWeather and moment.js - invalid date with js-geolocation in Germany

Tags: geolocation, momentjs

**Hey ho =)**

I wanted to create a Weather Plugin for my Website. So i choose the [simpleWeather](http://monkeecreate.com/jquery.simpleWeather/) Plugin.

The simpleWeather Plugin used the moment.js lib to get the last updated time. But the Plugin itself not provide a language option.

My standard location is "Kiel, Germany".

But it's not working and says "Invalid Date". 
I have no idea, why!

Can someone help me, please?

```
/* Does your browser support geolocation? */
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  $('.js-geolocation').show(); 
} else {
  $('.js-geolocation').hide();
}

/* Where in the world are you? */
$('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    getWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude); //load weather using your lat/lng coordinates
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {  
  getWeather('Kiel',''); //@params location, woeid //Get the initial weather.
});

function getWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    //20065908 KIEL woeid
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<ul>Today: <i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i><br />';
      html += '<li>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li></ul>';

      //Don't forget to include the moment.js plugin.
      var timestamp = moment(weather.updated);
      html += '<p>Weather updated '+moment(timestamp).fromNow()+'</p>';
      html += '<p>Weather updated at '+moment(timestamp).format('MM/DD/YY h:mma')+'</p>';

      for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++) {
        html += ''+weather.forecast[i].day+': <i class="icon-'+weather.forecast[i].code+ '"></i>';
      }

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/angel_crawford/pen/JYrvaQ)

I don't know how exactly the geolocation works... but I think that moment.js use the geolocation to set a language. 
So I tried to set the moment.js locale globaly to 'en', but it's also not working how I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Yahoo Weather (simpleWeather's data source) does not follow its own standard for date formatting... The `weather.updated` date in the response looks like this: `Tue, 20 Oct 2015 3:58 pm CEST`. This is not a standard date format, thus Moment.js cannot parse is correctly (because there are some not unique [time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), e.g. CST).

A quote from  [Yahoo Dev documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html):

> *pubDate:* The date and time this forecast was posted, in the
>   date format defined by RFC822 Section 5, for example Mon, 25 Sep
>   17:25:18 -0700.

Clearly, this is not the case. Moment.js would happily parse RFC822 formatted date. Yahoo should fix this issue.

However if you really want to use this feature and you have a fixed location, there is a way to parse the local date from Yahoo by changing this line:

```
var timestamp = moment(weather.updated);
```

to this:

```
var timestamp = moment(weather.updated, "ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm A");
```

And correct this date considering the visitor's time zone.

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed answer! This works perfect!